# LINQ-to-List and IEnumerable issues

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

I am querying an HTML file with LINQ-to-XML. It looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="Players">
        <div class="role">Goalies</div>
        <div class="name">John Smith</div>
        <div class="name">Shawn Xie</div>
        <div class="role">Right Wings</div>
        <div class="name">Jack Davis</div>
        <div class="name">Carl Yuns</div>
        <div class="name">Wayne Gortonia</div>
        <div class="role">Centers</div>
        <div class="name">Lutz Gaspy</div>
        <div class="name">John Jacobs</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a list of these folks like in a list of a structure called Players:

```
Structure Players
    Public Name As String
    Public Position As String
End Structure
```

But I've quickly found out I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to LINQ.

I've got this far in my queries:

```
Dim goalieList = From d In player.Elements _
                 Where d.Value = "Goalies" _
                 Select From g In d.ElementsAfterSelf _
                 Take While (g.@class <> "role") _
                 Select New Players With {.Position = "Goalie", _
                         .Name = g.Value}

Dim centersList = From d In player.Elements _
                  Where d.Value = "Centers" _
                  Select From g In d.ElementsAfterSelf _
                  Take While (g.@class <> "role") _
                  Select New Players With {.Position = "Centers", _
                         .Name = g.Value}
```

Which gets me down to the players by position, but then I can't do much with this afterwards the result type is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Player))`

What I want to do is add these two results to a new list, like:

```
Dim playersList As List(Of Players) = Nothing
playersList.AddRange(centersList)
playersList.AddRange(goalieList)
```

So that I can then query the list and use it. But it kicks the error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Players]]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Players]'

As you can see, I may really have no idea how to work with all these objects/classes. Does anyone have any insight on what I may be doing wrong and how I can resolve it?

**RESOLVED**: The LINQ query needs to return a single IEnumerable, like this:

```
Dim goalieList = From l In _
                    (From d In players.Elements _
                     Where d.Value = "Goalies" _
                     Select d.ElementsAfterSelf.TakeWhile(Function(f) f.@class <> "role")) _
                  Select New Players With {.Position = "Goalie", .Name = l.Value}
```

and then use `goalieList.ToList`

Comment: There are several ways you can go about doing this. My answer below is one way to do exactly what you want. You can also make use of Linq's Set operations to create a union of results. You can also construct a query that returns the results in one set,

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Good eye! I've fixed it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: aargh, you're right. fixed now. thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fail at VB, but in C# you would call ToList() on the centersList and goalieList.

So something like:

```
playersList.AddRange(centersList.ToList())
playersList.AddRange(goalieList.ToList())
```

Comment: You gave me a good hint here. I figured it out, I believe. The issue was that I had two select statements which was creating an iEnumerable within an iEnumerable. I changed my code to:

Dim goalieList = From l In (From d In players.Elements Where d.Value = "Goalies" Select d.ElementsAfterSelf.TakeWhile(Function(f) f.@class <> "role")) Select New Players With {.Position = "Goalie", .Name = l.Value}

which then returns a single iEnumerable. Witht this, I do as you suggested - playersList.AddRange(goalieList.ToList()) - and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that you have two Players classes? Otherwise, I don't see how you could possibly get that error message.

Looking into Reflector, WhereSelectEnumerableIterator implements IEnumerable, so the cast should succeed.